# Как расшифровать строку

Tags: php

Есть строка такого вида

```
xњURInГ0ьПF!R«х•¶7Q#vњ*О† /µ*‡ГE\^pћ†g€а_O[рRТ‡и
:™®н`і>Аг»ѓ]ћЙм>ћXQ    ЩAј|   їа?Ѕа‹Ю’Gи¦+ј‘ReќЄ°°|ЙJ’ћ2.¬лі±Є4U\hT?±nоЅНоєтRх›КKCћРfЫьIV\yе2vЌ·євВkWтх-ѕ+яй[~,ю(ZсіЉеckќЄ °5O)S­}FШ¦ЁнХUСzЁmJъНc[BK/”sК*ЕіХµq)е*4RІЉбћf»_&Ю ЕЬгМ’4АЈїG‚g>'ъІqMъyщ№pрЊ›…—@wpfN_WЎИҐWот[дђЯ-џВ-Lј6ДAв‘ѓXv§m,ТtЭ‹4Дy№ІV
NГґтO¶s^CJТА‹H,Mгю°пЧ3о¦ђ
ЩзцМТy№‡Le”вЯ\э:¦_Јґ=Rжэ|ґ»6
```

Каким образом можно раскодировать и узнать содержание данной строки?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server  nginx/1.2.3
Date    Tue, 24 Sep 2013 05:07:26 GMT
Content-Type    application/octet-stream
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Connection  close
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.17-1~dotdeb.0
Content-Length  390
```

Это ответ сервера

Answer (score 1):

По сути тут написано, что nginx отдал двоичный файл (вот ту самую строку). С виду строка похожа на ole объект возможно файл word или excel. Ну или видео какое-то. Вы же не скинули нам полностью заголовки в которых передается имя самого файла.

Comment: я тоже подумал, что это файл. 
Content-Type: application/octet-stream это же вроде когда php не может определить тип файла? 

поправьте, если ошибаюсь.

Comment: "Вы же не скинули нам полностью заголовки в которых передается имя самого файла." Нужно имя файла который отдает эти данные или имя файла который содержит эти данные? Если первое то это обычный php файла, а если второе то те заголовки что я указал выше, это все что нам возвращается.

Comment: Вы не рассказали нам саму историю данного вопроса. Констатировать я могу лиш тот факт, что php отдает бинарный файл (любой не знаю какой, может даже вирус). При чем длина файла 390 байт. Структура в файле есть судя с этой самой строки. Возможно вы его принимаете или читаете не в той кодировке. Но тот факт, что сайт шлет не текстовые данные а двоичные описан в заголовках: octet-stream

Если вы пытаетесь перехватить какие-то данные то давайте больше информации, если вам просто какой-то сайт такое отсылает и вы к этому отношение не имеете то скорее всего данные битые или предназначены не вам.

Comment: В ознакомительных целях, используя программу Charles Web Debugging, пытаемся перехватить данные передаваемые flash игрой для дальнейших манипуляций с ними. И вот в тупик поставил вот такой ответ сервера.

Comment: Значит логично, что сервер шлет вам какие-то структурированные данные. Они не закодированые это либо координаты лобо карта либо еще что-то. Надо дебажить флешку

Comment: А вы бы не могли подсказать какими средствами лучше воспользоваться для данных манипуляций?